# TypeError: backward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'grad_tensors' in pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, gradient

I have the following

```
w = torch.tensor([1.], requires_grad=True)
x = torch.tensor([2.], requires_grad=True)

a = torch.add(w, x)
b = torch.add(w, 1)

y0 = torch.mul(a, b)    # y0 = (x+w) * (w+1)
y1 = torch.add(a, b)    # y1 = (x+w) + (w+1)     


loss = torch.cat([y0, y1], dim=0)       # [y0, y1]

weight = torch.tensor([1., 2.])

loss.backward(grad_tensors=weight)
```

The above give me `TypeError: backward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'grad_tensors'`
I check the [website](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html) , the `grad_tensors` does live in the `backward`.

However, when I use

```
loss.backward(gradient=weight)
```

It works. `gradient` is not a parameters in `backward`. Any idea of that? my pytorch version is `1.7.0`. Thanks.

Comment: You are calling the [`torch.Tensor.backward`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.Tensor.backward), not `torch.autograd.backward`.

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to use `torch.autograd.backward` ? Also, what is the diffeent between those two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the [`torch.Tensor.backward`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/tensor.html#Tensor.backward), not `torch.autograd.backward`.

As for your second question about the difference b/w the two,  `torch.Tensor.backward` [internally calls](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/tensor.html#Tensor.backward) `torch.autograd.backward`, which calculates gradients of given tensors w.r.t. graph leaves.

```
torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
```

which corresponds to

```
torch.autograd.backward(tensors: self, grad_tensors: gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
```

Thus, below two are equivalent:

```
loss.backward(gradient=weight)
torch.autograd.backward(loss, weight)
```